Eclipse 2024-03 gets error trying to install the Vaadin plugin
Good, I have recently started working with Vaadin and in the videos I have been watching to learn how to install the plug-in to create projects with Vaadin.
I have gone to install this plug-in and when starting the installation it gives me different options:

Keep my installation the same and modify the items being installed to be compatible (does not install the plug-in)
Update my installation to be compatible with the items being installed (install the plug-in, but uninstall mylyn)
Show original error and build my own solution:

Basically it does not allow me to install the plug-in because of incompatibility with mylyn, how could I fix this error?

I have tried to reinstall eclipse, select the option to uninstall mylyn, but still when I create a project I get errors due to lack of mylyn and I do not know what else to do to install it.
I do not know if maybe it is my problem because of my lack of knowledge and it is not necessary to install this plug-in.

The Vaadin plugin you want to install does not work with the current Mylyn version you have, as it requires an older Mylyn version. This issue has been already reported here: https://github.com/vaadin/eclipse-plugin/issues/812

It's not necessary to install the plugin to create a Vaadin project. There are many different options you can choose from:

Use a Maven archetype:

mvn -B archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
-DarchetypeVersion=24.3.9 \
-DgroupId=org.example \
-DartifactId=my-webapp \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT


Go to https://start.vaadin.com/ to generate and download a project starter
Clone a suitable starter project from GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Avaadin+starter&type=repositories

If you're looking for older Vaadin versions (such as Vaadin 8), the easiest approach would be using a Maven archetype; just supply a suitable version number for the -DarchetypeVersion parameter.
PS. you can even apply the archetype in Eclipse by going to New -> New Maven Project and choose the vaadin-archetype-application from group id com.vaadin (or another relevant archetype) on the Select an Archetype screen.
